# Grocery app with price-per-shop and aisle-per-shop?

Tags: android, database, spreadsheet, table

Back in the old PalmOS days, I had a grocery app which had these features:

- You would enter any items yourself (obviously - that was in the pre-Smartphone days; no internet on the device)
- You would also enter all the shops you were frequenting.
- You would enter the price per item *per shop*. I.e., the app would keep track of the same item, and you had multiple prices. Also you could enter the price "per volume" or "per weight" for items that are regularly sold in non-standard quantities.
- You would then mark items as something you wanted to buy, and the app would show you all the shops you had to visit. When you entered a shop in the app, it would show you all the items and give an indication whether the item had the least price in that shop. You would tick off the items you bought.
- Also, you could enter the aisle the item was in, again per shop, so during shopping the items were automatically sorted by aisle.

Is there an Android app that has these two features (price-per-shop and aisle-per-shop), and is otherwise as light-weight as possible? I don't need anything else - no cloud/online features, no calorie counting, no social features, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of them, just type on Google:

[grocery shopping app compare prices](https://www.google.com/search?q=grocery%20shopping%20app%20compare%20prices&rlz=1C1CSMH_enCH1017CH1017&oq=compare%20Grocery%20Shopping%20App&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i8i30j0i390i650l3.7386j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you. I am specifically looking for an app which works like the one I described above. All apps I found in your google link focus on "modern" features (mostly restricted to items on sale; collaborative data entry; meal planning; sharing of data between family members and so on and forth). I am not interested in any of that and would prefer a lean, non-bloated solution.

Answer (score 0):

[My app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.vporton.local_shops) provides these features (enter prices yourself and easily find the cheapest). Moreover, my app supports product categories (like "Lunch"), so you can easily find the cheapest lunch among different kinds of lunch.

I am now investigating how to add product lists from online databases, to reduce the work of user entering prices by himself.